# Syntax error in teradata query : " Select * must contain a FROM CLAUSE"

Tags: teradata

The below TERADATA query is giving "SELECT * MUST HAVE A FROM CLAUSE" Error.
Previously it was working fine. If anyone can help.

```
Select * 
FROM 
 ( SELECT 4000 *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) rnum 
   from dbname.tablename 
   where (1=1)
 ) A 
where rnum>2000 and rnum <=4000
```

Comment: `SELECT 4000 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1)` looks pretty suspicious to me.  Not sure about the 4000 bit. But because you are selecting more that just *, you have to qualify the * - `tablename.*, row_number....`

Comment: from dbname.tablename .... was working before? ... Sounds like a book example.. and no, it doesn't work because it's bad SQL

Comment: This was never *working fine*. The `*` must be qualified. The processing of the `ROW_NUMBER` will be totally skewed and will not return the same result when you run the query twice. Maybe you ment `select top 4000`, but that's useless because it's processed *after* the OLAP-function.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, **tablename.*** was the solution. I missed that part in the query and the error started coming.